# Freeradius EAP-PEAP with LDAP

Tags: ldap, freeradius, radius

I use a freeradius server acting as 802.1x authentication server. Windows OS use EAP-PEAP encryption by default. That means Windows sends out an encrypted credential to my radius server, and I can not decode it to a clear text password. But without a clear text password, how can I do authenticating in ldap server? Because passwords stored in ldap server are encrypted by some algorithms like MD5, how can I compare the two encrypted passwords encrypted by different algorithms?

Comment: Update: If I store the passwords to LDAP in clear text, I can use EAP-PEAP. But it's not safe, the administrator of LDAP server can access all passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.  See this [compatibility matrix](http://deployingradius.com/documents/protocols/compatibility.html).

You can store passwords in LDAP as Cleartext or as NT-Passwords (unsalted MD4 of 16bit UTF encoding).

As Windows now supports EAP-TTLS-PAP most people use that where they don't have access to the cleartext password or active directory server.

Comment: EAP-TTLS-PAP is a good and my final solution. But it is only supported by Windows 8 and later. If clients are Windows 7 or previous, there's an easy and open source tool: https://github.com/Amebis/GEANTLink

Comment: The administrator would always be able to access all passwords. They don't need to be in cleartext, as they could simply create a proxy process eavesdropping and loggin password change attempts or cleartext authentication attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Came here looking for the same answer as to how to setup FreeRadius + LDAP + EAP-PEAP for 802.1X WiFi

After some research and more googling , it turns out you can set it up,  with very little effort , just need to change a setting in `/etc/freeradius/mods-enabled/eap`
search for peap type eap , there should be something like

```
    ## EAP-PEAP
    peap {
        tls = tls-common
        default_eap_type = mschapv2
        ...
   }
```

change that to

```
    peap {
        tls = tls-common
        default_eap_type = gtc
        ...
   }
```

restart the service and try your connection

Check these links for more details
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Protected_Access
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol#EAP_Generic_Token_Card_(EAP-GTC)
http://lists.freeradius.org/pipermail/freeradius-users/2014-September/073992.html
https://support.google.com/a/answer/9089736
https://support.google.com/a/answer/9048516?hl=en&ref_topic=9048334
https://community.ui.com/questions/Guide-to-get-Unifi-FreeRadius-Google-LDAP-G-Suite-set-up-in-docker/36af593f-73b1-4943-8e22-9a81b10db9ae

Comment: This enables authenticating against the internal FreeRadius database w/ EAP-PEAP, and then using LDAP to authorize against the domain/directory, but it doesn't support authenticating via EAP-PEAP against the LDAP.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that!

If you do not save password in LDAP in cleartext or ntPassword, the only choice you have is using eap-ttls with pap.
And you should change configuration of your clients to send eap-ttls requests instead of eap-peap.